# Does IRF3710 have a schottky diode inside?

Tags: mosfet, schottky

I'm using IRF3710 MOSFET H-bridge for 40A 12V motor driver. Should I use a schottky diode inside or should I use a separate one?

Comment: What does the datasheet say? Your question is if you need one is unanswerable without much more information, including schematic.

Comment: The body diode that is inherent to most MOSFETs is **NOT** Schottky.  Rather: it is an ordinary silicon diode.

Answer (score 1):

The IRF3710 has a body diode inside. See: [IRF3710 - Datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3710.pdf)

*H-Bridge:*

Diodes parallel to the MOSFET's (see schematic below) will ensure that the peak transistor voltage is limited to the input DC voltage and will also provide a conduction path for the magnetizing load current.
*(See: R. W. Erickson and D. Maksimović, Fundamentals of power electronics. New York: Kluwer Academic, 2004.)*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBfn8C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Body-Diode*

The connection of bulk an drain in a MOSFET results in a body diode. Thus, a MOSFET always has such a diode. ([Information about the Body Diode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_MOSFET#Body_diode))

Body diodes can be used in applications. However, usually they have a high reverse recovery time.
If needed the body diode can be blocked with two diodes.

Comment: They all do....

Comment: Yes =). I added some information.

Comment: Where you write "Full-Bridge", I think you mean H-Bridge or "Full-H" (maybe nitpicky). Also, they are usually constructed of 2 NFETs and 2 PFETs (you have drawn 4 NFETS). And the diodes need to be connected at the centers, otherwise what's the point of have two on each side?

Comment: Oh, you fixed the diodes...

Comment: You are right, I will change it to H-Bridge.

Comment: Is there any MOSFETS (or IGBTS) that can handle back EMF without using any external diodes? ie, is there any MOSFET models that can implement above h bridge without D1, D2,D3 and D4?